# error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

I tried some ways to fix this, but this is an error yet.
Can anyone help me?

```
public GameObject Xvreli = null;
public int zPos;
public int enemyCount;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(EnemyDrop());
}

IEnumerator EnemyDrop()
{
    while (Xvreli.name < 5)
    {
        zPos = Random.Range(0, 1000);
        Instantiate(Xvreli, new Vector3(0, 0, zPos), Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        Xvreli.name += 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does it mean if a name is less than 5? Do you mean the length of the name? Or is the name a text representation of a number?

Comment: it's prefab name

Comment: Please give some example values for `name` and the outcome of `name < 5`

Comment: Yes, but it is a string, not a number. Therefore you cannot compare it to a number. If the string *contains* a numeric value, e.g. "1", you can convert it to a number using e.g. `Convert.ToInt32(Xvreli.name)`. But also the `+= 2` will not work with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the error is quite self-explanatory..

It looks like what you wanted to do is parsing the `name` value to an int value and back e.g. using [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse)

```
int nameInt;
while((nameInt = int.Parse(Xvreli.name)) < 5)
{
    ...

    Xvreli.name = (nameInt + 2).ToString();
}
```

or also [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) (doesn't throw format exception)

```
while (int.TryParse(Xvreli.name, out var nameInt) && nameInt < 5)
{
    ...

    Xvreli.name = (nameInt + 2).ToString();
}
```

Comment: @BesoJgharkava careful though, if the name would be anything that cannot be converted to a number, you will get a `FormatException`